# Automount Shared Folder in VirtualBox 5.0.2/VBoxManage Intern Procedure

Tags: linux, virtualbox, automount

First I wondered, that I found nothing to the topic. Maybe I’m not so good searching?

However, following command creates a new Shared Folder in VBoxManage:

```
.\VboxManage.exe sharedfolder add <NameOfVM> --name <NameOfSharedFolder> --hostpath <PATH>
```

Is there a way to set an option for mounting automatically? In the GUI for VirtualBox you can also set an option "Auto-mount" without doing anything inside the VM.

I found this post:
https://askubuntu.com/q/252853/448613 But there is just a solution with *fstab* and no statement, that VBoxManage can't automount.

**EDIT:** So does anybody know, what the `auto-mount`does internally? Is it just a script, which is put inside the VM via the GuestAdditions, which does:

```
$ mount –t vboxsf vboxsf /mnt/tmp
```

The solution - btw it’s in [the official documentation](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf) in the list with commands (Chapter 8.2), but not in the closer description:

```
.\VboxManage.exe sharedfolder add <NameOfVM> --name <NameOfSharedFolder> --hostpath <PATH> --automount
```

Not a surprise, that it’s `automount`, I tried this, but it seems that I had an error at another place then. Nevertheless, this command works with an existing VM in `NameOfVM`. The second part of this topic would still be interesting.